# How to remove unwanted performance overlay in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So, about a week ago I saw that in CS:GO, a random FPS + Min + AVG + Max  + CPU + GPU always shows up on the upper-left side of my screen. When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it changes to the upper-right side. Pushing it again moves it to the lower-right side. Again, lower-left side! It irritates me because it's not only in the main menu, but also when I am in a game...

I have noticed that when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> it toggles it on or off, but I would rather not have it at all. How can I disable these shortcuts?

Comment: umm, what is the question here? How to disable this key shortcut?

Comment: Something like that, yeah... I found out when I press SHIFT + O It shows up or goes away, where can I remove this Shortcut?

Comment: A screenshot would help. Otherwise there is no such thing as a Shift + O overlay shortcut in CS:GO. Try looking at your GPU's software.

Answer (score 3):

CS:GO does not have such a performance overlay option by default. You must have either added a `net_graph` configuration or installed another program like Afterburner/RivaTuner. I can't be sure without seeing a screenshot but it sounds more like a weird `net_graph` setup. If it is a program though, you should be able to easily disable that in its options or just uninstall it.

`net_graph` is a console command that has to be run or bound to a key every time CS:GO runs. The only way I know to do this is through an `autoexec.cfg` file.
This should be located:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg\autoexec.cfg`
Although it will depend on where you installed CS:GO.

Once you locate that file, disabling it will be as simple as just deleting the file. I assume you copied that file there for a reason though, so if there's some other configuration in there you want, you should open it and just remove any lines with `net_graph` in them.